# Regularization hyperparameter tuning without cross validation

Tags: cross-validation, regularization

Given a model on the observation data vector $y$ at coordinate vector $x$
$$M(f,\lambda) := (1-\lambda)L(y,f(x))+\lambda J(f) $$
where $\lambda\in[0,1]$, $L$ is a loss function and $J$ a roughness function and $f$ is a function of $x$. I perform
$$f_\lambda=\text{argmin}_f \,M(f,\lambda)$$

The standard method for tuning $\lambda$ is cross validation. In order to save on computational cost, is it completely nuts to minimize some function over $\lambda$, say
$$\min_\lambda\, N(\lambda,a)$$
where
$$N(\lambda,a):=(1-a)\ln L(y,f_\lambda(x)) +a\ln J(f_\lambda)$$
for some chosen $a\in[0,1]$? Are there other related approaches for cheaply tuning the regularization parameter?

I suppose in principle for any given $\lambda_c$ obtained from cross validation there is always an $a$ such that $\lambda_c$ is the value $\lambda$ takes to minimize $N(\lambda,a)$ for that particular $a$. So I see there is much ambiguity in this question. But I am hoping to hear some empirical experience of obtaining directly a $N$ function.

Comment: It looks like in your $N(\lambda)$ the $a$ plays the role that $\lambda$ had before - it even looks like finding the optimal $a$ could amount to finding the optimal $\lambda$, in which case the  $N(\lambda)$ isn't going to help you to find $\lambda$... people do cross-validation for a reason...

Comment: @Lewian: Are you saying the same thing as the first sentence of my last paragraph?

Comment: I don't quite understand that sentence, so I don't know.

Comment: @Lewian: I edited that sentence. Is it clear to you now?

Comment: Maybe, but certainly this is not what I was saying. You make a mathematical statement which may be true or false, I don't know. What I was saying was mainly that introducing a new parameter $a$ of which it is not clear how to choose it doesn't seem to make the problem of finding another parameter $\lambda$ any easier. And on top of that that the role played by the $a$ seems to be very similar to the role played by $\lambda$ before, so it looks like you're only pushing the problem around rather than getting closer to solving it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$N(\lambda, a)$ in general is not a good function for tuning the regularization parameter $\lambda$ without more constraint. In general, $L(y,f_L(x))=0$ for $f_L(x)=y$ and $J(f)=0$ for some $f=f_J$. Then $\ln(L(y,f_L))=\ln(J(f_J))=-\infty$. Obviously $f_{\lambda=0}=f_L\,\bigvee\, f_{\lambda=1}=f_J\implies N(\lambda,a)=-\infty$. Thus there is no regularization at all.

A good candidate for $N(\lambda,a)$ may be
$$N(\lambda,a):=(1-a)\ln\big(1+L(y,f_\lambda(x))\big)+a\ln \big(1+J(f_\lambda)\big)$$
avoiding $-\infty$ as a function value.